# Why is my ItemsControl not render ILookup<T,V> when set as ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class with a property `Errors` defined as:

```
public MultiLookup<string, Exception> Errors { get; private set; }
```

[MultiLookup](https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/cbd12ce208ec4a69ea95934ae4bb9eae) is of type [ILookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291(v=vs.110).aspx) as defined:

```
public class MultiLookup<TKey, TValue,TCollection> : ILookup<TKey, TValue>
```

This is bound to the [ItemsSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) property of an ItemsControl defined in XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Key}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**No items are rendered**

Inspecting the [live property explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx) one can see that there are no items in the control being rendered. The stack panel should have 4 items in it.

[image]

However there are 4 keys in the lookup table as shown in the [live property explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx) within Visual Studio, during a debug session.

[image]

Why do the 4 items not get rendered?

Comment: Have you tried RelativeSource binding, instead of Element binding. You seems to have added Error in ExceptionInfo class. Error is not property of UserControl.

Comment: I think I know. The collection is not observable. No events are raised if the number of items changes. Stupid error.

Comment: @Tilak 'Root' is an ExceptionInfo object. You can see that the binding is working because it has 4 elements in it.

Comment: @brad Does your first comment mean that the problem is solved? Then please write an answer or delete the question.

Comment: I will suggest to delete it.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's he problem. Only a guess.

Comment: @Versatile If you added a close vote please remove it. There is now a solution for the question.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing No I didn't add any close vote. Still don't have that privilege ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons here.

1. My [MultiLookup](https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/cbd12ce208ec4a69ea95934ae4bb9eae) does not implement INotifyCollectionChanged.
2. Even if you manually call `Items.Refresh` on the `ItemsControl` the binding does not update the ItemsControl.

The solution is simple. Create an immutable version of the collection that I update on every change.

```
    private readonly MultiLookup<string, Exception, List<Exception>>
             _Errors;

    [Reactive]public ILookup<string, Exception> Errors 
            { get; private set; }
```

where `_Errors` is the mutable version for internal handling and `Errors` is the immutable version which raises `INPC` events. I'm using `ReactiveUI.Fody` to implement INPC

On every change to the mutable version I just call

```
// Create a new immutable lookup on every error change.
Errors = _Errors
            .SelectMany(p => p.Select(i => new {p.Key, i}))
            .ToLookup(o => o.Key, o => o.i);
```

It now updates the ItemsControl correctly.

I could also have implemented [MultiLookup](https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/cbd12ce208ec4a69ea95934ae4bb9eae) with `INotifyCollectionChanged` to get a similar effect. Given that the expected size of this collection will always be very small ( less than 10 ) there is little overhead in generating a new copy each time. INotifyCollectionChanged` is also quite complex to get working correctly for a data structure like a lookup.